# gtk3 drawing failure for widget 'GtkDrawingArea' : out of memory

Tags: mingw, gtk3, cairo

I trying to write charting widget for gtk. All work well for me under ubuntu, but when i trying to compile my app for Windows throught mingw my app causes many warnings in terminal and widget don't drawing all things what i need. Can anyone help me? And sorry for my bad English.
Code on [github](https://github.com/Danili4/gtk-chart).

Warnings in shell: `Gtk-WARNING: **: drawing failure for widget 'GtkDrawingArea' : out of memory`